# AxWindowsMediaPlayer plays the same video even though the stream changed

Tags: vb.net, windows-media-player

I'm using AxWindowsMediaPlayer to play video from a stream URL. And it works good, but sometimes when the video changes on the server/stream, and I restart WMP it still plays the old video.

Do I need to reset the buffer or cache before playing restarting to force it to re-download the video? Or does it have something to do with playlists? Because the player displays something like "Playlist 1" even though I'm setting the stream using this:

```
AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.URL = "http://192.168.1.76:8888/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to reset it using this method:

```
AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.Ctlcontrols.stop()
AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.URL = ""
AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer.currentPlaylist.clear()
```